# Compilation warning not present (GCC and g++)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3
  4 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  5 {
  6     int bret = 1;
  7     bret - 2;
  8
  9     printf("bret=%d",bret);
 10     return 0;
 11 }
```

In line:7, there was no left hand operator to reveice the value, still compiler was not generating any warning, GCC and g++ both. Is there anyintended purpore behind this?

[ADDED/EDIT]
As per comment I shall get warning only after using following flags: -Wall -Wextra

```
[debd@test]$gcc -Wall -Wextra test2.c
test2.c: In function 'main':
test2.c:7: warning: statement with no effect
test2.c:4: warning: unused parameter 'argc'
test2.c:4: warning: unused parameter 'argv'
[debd@test]$
```

Comment: There should be a warning, as long as you've enabled a sensible warnings; GCC is fairly quiet by default. Try `-Wall -Wextra`. Or `-Wunused-value` to enable just that specific warning.

Comment: yes...I got below warning, thanks.. 
[debd@test]$gcc -Wall -Wextra test2.c
test2.c: In function 'main':
test2.c:7: warning: statement with no effect
test2.c:4: warning: unused parameter 'argc'
test2.c:4: warning: unused parameter 'argv'
[debd@test]$

Comment: Indeed, you're not using the function parameters, so you get a warning about that. You can fix that warning by changing the signature to `int main()`. (More generally, you can fix that warning for unused parameters in C++ by not naming the parameter, or in C with `(void)argc;` to explicitly ignore the value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the language is concerned, there's no error - a statement is not required to have a side effect.

However, since a statement that does nothing is almost certainly a mistake, most compilers will warn about it. Yours will, but only if you enable that warning via the command line arguments.

You can enable just that warning with `-Wunused-value`, but I suggest you enable a decent set of warnings (including this one) with `-Wall -Wextra`.

As you found, this will also give a warning that the function parameters are unused. Since this is `main`, you can easily fix it by changing the signature to not have any parameters:

```
int main()
```

More generally, to avoid the warning if you need to ignore parameters, C++ allows you not to name them:

```
int main(int, char**)
```

and both languages allow you to explicitly use but ignore the value

```
(void)argc;
(void)argv;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bret - 2;
```

is an *expression statement* and it is has no side-effect.

C does not requires any warning for this statement. The compiler is free to add or not an informative warning to say the statement has no effect. The compiler can optimize out the statement.